# Conditionally turn change class and rel based on a custom field using a php template in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is a plugin theme issue.
My plugin works with this template page that I have made.(modified)

The orginal file [product-image.php](http://snippi.com/s/9yyxtpc).
My modified file [product-image-360.php](http://snippi.com/s/by9o7on)

I have added 3 custom field to the product post.

- `magnified_image_filename` - gives the plugin the name of the file that is needed for it to run;
- `magnified_image` - gives the path to the image;
- `360` - class field is used to identify the post to see whether or not to enable pretty photo in the post.

This bit of code is really clever for allowing you to turn off a feature for a globally assigned class i.e `prettyPhoto`. This allows me to Enable the `prettyPhoto` from the featured images  and turn it off when I include a class field of 360 yes for post and product images.

```
    global $post,$woocommerce;
    $threesixty = get_post_meta($post->ID, '360', true);
    if ($threesixty == '') {
    wp_register_script( 'prettyPhoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
    }
```

However I now have two `product-image.php` templates. How do I combine them into a conditional statement that changes the rel and class attributes depending upon a custom field of 360?

Comment: What are the conditions that we want `$threesixty` to meet? We can use some easy ternary operator methods to decide which classes/rel's to use in our `<a>`.

Comment: The conditions are if post has custom field 360 yes, then prettyPhoto will not display, allowing me to use a 3rd party plugin for images. I want 360 to include class="Magic360" and rel="filename".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if they don't have a '360' field, then we'll assume that get_post_meta($post->ID, '360', true); will return false.

```
<a 
  itemprop="image" 
  href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" 
  class="<?php echo (TRUE == ($threesixty = get_post_meta($post->ID, '360', true))) ? 'Magic360' : 'somethingElse';?>" 
  rel="<?php echo (TRUE == ($threesixty = get_post_meta($post->ID, '360', true))) ? 'filename:'.$split_name.'-{col}.jpg; magnify:true; magnify-filename:'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'magnified_image_filename', true).'-{col}.jpg' : 'somethingElse';?>"
>
  //img stuff here
</a>
```